# mapserv calculate BBOX instead of requiring user to provide it

Tags: wms, mapserver

We have a requirement to email out a map showing a particular feature in our database.  When the query is made to generate the map all it has is a feature id.  All the queries I've seen to MapServer/WMS include a BBOX.  Is it possible to calculate the BBOX  based on the feature id?

The feature id will be stored in a PostGIS/PostgreSQL database.

Comment: can your client access the database directly?

Comment: Its possible but I was trying to do it with just one query.

Comment: You can use a WFS call to GetFeatureById

Comment: All WMS GetMap requests require a BBOX, with extents specified in the coordinate reference system of the request data.  That's not specific to a MapServer WMS. Any BBOX can be specified, it doesn't have to match the  extent of the feature (but if if it doesn't coincide, you'll get no map image)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither the WMS protocol nor any of the other MapServer APIs have a mechanism to automatically set the map position and zoom level based on a geometry object.

You have to retrieve the bounding box with a separate query (through WFS, or directly to the database).